# Am I organizing this sentence correctly and using the semicolon correctly?

Tags: lists, semicolons

I have this somewhat complex sentence that is part of a college admissions essay. I am trying to say a lot in one sentence, so I tried to use the comma and semicolon to break apart the pieces, but something doesn't sound right about it.

Here's my sentence:

I think science, biology and physics in particular, are really fascinating; and math is obviously an important subject for life, but I’ve found that art has taught me a whole new way of thinking and therefore has had the most influence on me.

Is this the right way to organize this sentence? How can I improve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The awkwardness comes because your subject and verb don't agree in the first clause. Science is really fascinating, not science are really fascinating. You can fix this by either changing the subject to "the sciences" or change your verb to are as I have done here. One of the correct sentences is here:

> I think science, biology and physics in particular, is really
>   fascinating, and math is obviously an important subject for life, but
>   I've found art is the subject that has taught me a whole new way of
>   thinking and therefore has had the most influence on me.